# placing a div over an image

Tags: html

I want to place a div over an image.  As of now I think I want it towards the top left of the image.  This needs to be compatible with views on different screen sizes so I don't think an absolute positioned div will work...  How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the image as a background of a div and insert another div in the first one.
Something like this:

```
<div style="background: url('myimg.png'); width: '100px'; height: '100px' float: left;">
   <div style="float: left;">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Test will appear on the top left side of the image.

Comment: Thank you.  When I preview this in IE my font color changes and the div width increases to 100% of the div it is inside.                                                                  .divlocation {
 color: #FFF;
 float:left;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   max-width: 100px;
}  <div style="background:url(../images/circleimage.jpg); width: 311px; height: 211px; float: center;">
   <div class="divlocation">thisdivsucks</div>

Comment: is this not IE compatable?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to de.

Comment: I want to have a div on top of an image.  So I followed your directions but it isn't working.  Is it possible that the problem is that these two divs are inside tables and other divs?

Comment: Yes this is compatible with all browsers I checked it.
Not sure but in the code you pasted you are missing: '</div>' in the end is it a pasting error?

Comment: yes, it is a pasting error.  It works in designer view in dreamweaver but when I preview it in any browser it doesn't work properly.  It's taking on properties of the table it's inside.  How can I change that?

Comment: You'll need to overwrite the attributes you want to act differently in the divs style.
For example if the table got the attribute: background-color: #343434
and you'd like the div to have a different background-color, you'll need to add this attribute in the div style with the new color.
I hope that's what you meant in your question.

Comment: that's what I meant.  Even when I do that it's not working.  Grrr.  The code is right and in designer view its right but it changes when I view it in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` already starts at the top left of its parent element. Since it's a block level element you will have to specify a width or else it will take up all the available space.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pd39B/

```
<div></div>
<img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/2642324404/46d743534606515238a9a12cfb4b264a.jpeg">

div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit trickier ...

**Placing a div over an iframe/video...**

(just replace the iframe w/ your image) ....

trick part is for video ... you must add ... ?wmode=transparent ... to the end of the src url...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML > 
<style type="text/css"> 
.Container {position:relative;  float:left;  border: 1px solid #0f0; }
.Vid {position:absolute; top:7px; left:7px; width:90%; height:90%;  }
.Lyr {position:absolute; top:7px; left:7px; width:90%; height:90%; background-color: #a3E1a6;  opacity:0.5; }
</style>

<div id="Cntr0" class="Container" style="width:220px; height:140px;">
    <iframe id="frm0" class="Vid" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/y1VVXrUdO2s?wmode=transparent' frameborder='0'></iframe>
    <div id="div0" class="Lyr" ></div>
</div>
```